# Security issue while creating Website with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have created an Admin portal using firebase which  shows the details of the users registered in my android app. As soon as they register in my app, the user is created inside the firebase Auth. Now I am concerned about the security of the site as my firebase API key is visible to everyone. So if they use that key, then they can easily access my firebase database and fetch the data using a simple javascript. So I wanted to know any solution to avoid this security problem???

Comment: by firebase API key you mean this => https://fireapp-2a4b1.firebaseio.com/ correct

Comment: No the one which we write inside script tag for web

  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSdsd4r4r1UU9gWkRhvgfCXCM_ywrpgZRI",
    authDomain: "crsfdsfsdfsdfveebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://credsdfaisdfsfsdfsfdd.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "csdfsdn17-f96ad.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "12953434344207"
  };

Comment: @AyushBharadwaj I haven't used firebase for the web. I have used it for android app. You can see this for reference https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/-u2wBWSETds/MWP5BWtnFwAJ